# How to get the email/name of the user that initiates a Jira Webhook

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm working on a internal integration with Jira and I need to perform an action when a ticket is moved between boards. I've setup a Automation trigger that sends a web requeest but I'm not sure how to get the name of the user that performs the action.

Although Atlassian's docs are all over the place, I found out that there is an `action` object that is [passed](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/automation-webhooks/#adding-a-webhook-to-an-automation-rule) but nothing more.

Comment: Perform the action you mean the person who moved the ticket ?

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the ticket history?